# MVC - Getting Textbox value which is set by jQuery script

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am setting value for the `Textbox` with jQuery. I have a `Textbox` as follows :-

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Location, new { @disabled = "disabled" })
```

In `jQuery`, I set value for this `Textbox` :-

```
$('#Location').val('xyz');
```

On `HTTPPOST`, I have following Code :-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Location(FormCollection form, Location mod)
{
    string getLocation = mod.Location;
    string getLocation1 = form["FromEsiLocation"];
    // Both these methods are unable to retrieve the value which is set by jQuery
}
```

How to get this Value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **disabled textboxes or any other field** values can never be posted but you can use a workaround for this just take hidden field for `Location` and set its value and get the hidden field `#Location` value on post controller action .

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Location, new { @disabled = "disabled", @id="MyLocation" })

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Location)  //take one more hidden field.
```

Comment: what is another element i can use in place of `TextBox`?